# intertools.combinations - how to use?

Tags: python, combinations

Here is my code:

```
import itertools
print(itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2))
```

I expect output `AB AC AD BC BD CD` as per [intertools docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations),
but I get `<itertools.combinations object at 0x030A2A50>`

What is wrong?

Comment: It returns an iterator you can convert it to `list` with `list()` function .Or pass it within a list comprehension to join it, you can also pass it to another functions that accepts iterables like `map`

Comment: @Kasramvd it returns a tuple of list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list_comprehension` along with `join` function.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print([''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2)])
['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generator so it has value only when called with next(). This is for memory saving purposes, the values are generated only when needed so you save the space in memory - only one value is returned at time.

This is the same case like with range and xrange.

Use `print tuple(itertools.combinations('ABCD',2))` to cast it to tuple and force generating all values at once.